# how to use datetimepicker on Delphi 7

Tags: mysql, delphi, date, datetime, sqlyog

How to use `TDateTimePicker` with time format (hour:minute:second)?
 
I tried this code:

```
Sql.text:= ('select * from namatabel where namafield between '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('yyyy/mm/dd', datetimepicker1.date))+' and '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('yyyy/mm/dd', datetimepicker2.date))+' and field order by field ASC');
```

Also this code:

```
Sql.text:= ('select * from tablename where fieldname between '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss', datetimepicker1.date))+' and '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss', datetimepicker2.date))+' and fieldname order by fieldname ASC');
```

Also this code:

```
Sql.text:= ('select * from tablename where fieldname between '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss', datetimepicker1.datetime))+' and '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss', datetimepicker2.datetime))+' and fieldname order by fieldname ASC');
```

but those wont work, help me to correct them.
I'm using [SQLYog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) against a MySQL database.

UPDATE

@Jens Borrisholt i try this code before, but it doesnt work either

```
SQL.Add('SELECT meteran.kd_meter as no,kamar.nama,meteran.waktu,meteran.meter '+
        'FROM meteran,kamar WHERE kamar.idkamar = meteran.idkamar AND meteran.waktu BETWEEN :tgl1 and :tgl2 and waktu group by waktu asc');
ParamByName('tgl1').AsString:=FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',DateTimePicker1.DateTime);
ParamByName('tgl2').AsString:=FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',DateTimePicker2.DateTime); end;
DBGrid2.DataSource.DataSet:=MyQuery2;
```

Comment: Learn how to use parameters and you might lose this format hell. Well, you might because of some DBMS' through ADO *complications* as far as I remember (you seem to be using MySQL, and probably ADO ?).

Comment: What is *Sql.text* here, i.e. is that from a Delphi component you are using? What does SqlYog have to do with the question? Please [edit] your question further.

Comment: ya, i use SQL.text to insert, update, and select database. im not using ADO but i use MyQuery Access. is that different? cuz i am still learning this programming thing.

Comment: Your question is unrelated to date/time picker controls. It would benefit you to understand why.

Comment: Btw, you don't need parentheses around the string value in a Delphi string-assignment statement.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is it unrelated? it supposed to be the one filtering between the data, am i correct?

Comment: @MartynA aren't they needed?i mean to convert the value.

Comment: It's unrelated because a date time from a picker is no different from any other date time. Knowing that would let you isolate the problem.

Comment: @MartynA is telling you that `str := ('foo')` is the same as `str := 'foo'`

Comment: okay, thanks @DavidHeffernan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mt sure what is your exact requirement.ill try to help you.

I)If you want to compare the **date** of the datetimepicker against a **date** of datetime field in table,

SQL.Add(format('select * from tablename where cast ([my_date_time_var] as date) between %s and %s ' ,[Quotedstr(FormatDateTime('MM/DD/YYYY',(datepicker1.Date))),Quotedstr(FormatDateTime('MM/DD/YYYY',(datepicker2.Date)))]))

II)If you want to compare the **date time** of the datetimepicker against a **date time** of datetime field in the table,

SQL.Add(format('select * from tablename where my_date_time_var between %s and %s ' ,[Quotedstr(FormatDateTime('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS',(datepicker1.DateTime))),Quotedstr(FormatDateTime('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS',(datepicker2.DateTime)))]));

III)If you want to compare the **time** of the datetimepicker against a **time** of datetime field in table,

SQL.Add(format('select * from tablename where cast ([my_date_time_var] as time) between %s and %s ' ,[Quotedstr(FormatDateTime('HH:MM:SS',(datepicker1.time))),Quotedstr(FormatDateTime('HH:MM:SS',(datepicker2.Time)))]))

Please let me know if your requirement is not the same

Comment: wah, thanks! already solved. i put too many 'and' on the code. thanks for letting me know @Binitta Mary.

Comment: you have errors in your SQL : **1.)** `'select * from tablename where cast ([my_date_time_var] as time) ...'` will not work in MySql. **2.)** `where .... between %s and %s ' , ... (FormatDateTime('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS',(....)...` will also not work.

Comment: Sorry I dont know that you are working with MySQL...I gave you MSSQL query as example.I hope the formating will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong

- **and fieldname** is too much

---

shortened with data

NOT OK

```
Sql.text:= 'select * from tablename where fieldname between "2006-06-11"'+
           'and "2006-06-19" and fieldname order by fieldname ASC';
```

OK

```
Sql.text:= 'select * from tablename where fieldname between "2006-06-11" '+
           'and "2006-06-19" order by fieldname ASC';
```

---

example valid SQL with data

```
select * from auktionen where auktionende between '2006-06-11' and '2006-06-19' order by auktionende ASC;
```

All together with your code. without **and waktu**

```
BETWEEN :tgl1 and :tgl2 and waktu
```

---

```
MyQuery2.Close;
MyQuery2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT meteran.kd_meter as no,kamar.nama,meteran.waktu,meteran.meter '+
        'FROM meteran,kamar WHERE kamar.idkamar = meteran.idkamar'+
        ' AND meteran.waktu BETWEEN :tgl1 and :tgl2'+
        ' group by waktu';
MyQuery2.ParamByName('tgl1').AsString:=FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',DateTimePicker1.Date);
MyQuery2.ParamByName('tgl2').AsString:=FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',DateTimePicker2.Date);
DBGrid2.DataSource := DataSource1;
MyQuery2.Open;
```

Comment: yes, you right. i put 'and' too much. thanks @moskito-x

Comment: @WirahAryaMardjani : Can you tell me why you have a question checked to be correct, does not mention the problem with the incorrect **and** ?